# Is it possible to access all child of a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to select a div's all child divs with a specified class using jQuery?

For example:
If I click on a div it should toggle the clicked .name div's all children with .content class(div1,div2,div3).

The html:

```
<div class="name">
    Name of div 1
    <div class="content">
        Content of div 1
    </div>
    <div class="name">
        Name of div 2
        <div class="content">
            Content of div 2
        </div>

        <div class="name">
            Name of div 3
            <div class="content">
                Content of div 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
$(function() 
{
    $('.name').click(function()
    {
       $(this).children('.content').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I've tried this script, but it's select the divs on the first level only.

Comment: I've tried that one too, but that's also select the first level only.

Comment: What if you click on `div2` (2and3 .content opens) and than you decide to click DIV1 .... What should happen? (I think your problem is much more complicated than you thought at first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me explain an issue as result what you're trying to do

If you decide to click on **DIV 2** the **CONTENT 2** and **3** should open,
but if than you click **DIV 1** a total mess will happen:

DIV 1 will open but all the other will close.

**[EXAMPLE WITH ISSUE (PRESENT IN OTHER ANSWERS)](http://jsbin.com/tefik/2/edit)**

**To prevent that**
you should store the *is clicked or not* state directly into the clicked DIV

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/tefik/3/edit)**

```
$('.name').click(function(ev){
  ev.stopPropagation();
  var io = this.io ^= 1; // Toggle 1/0 state
  $('.content', this)[io?"slideDown":"slideUp"](function(){
    $(this).closest('.name')[0].io = io; // Store state also to all other
  });
});
```

- `ev.stopPropagation();` prevents the click to navigate up the DOM triggering the same function on not targeted elements (with same className)
- `var io = this.io ^= 1;` toggles using the XOR ^ bitwise operator a 1/0 value (later used as boolean) directly into the element Object custom `io` (or name it as you like) property (or name it as you like).
- Than what we do is: by using the *Conditional Operator (?:)* we use the toggled `this.io` value `1` or `0` as boolean, and if value is `1` (`true`) do a `slideDown` else, logically a `slideUp` for every `$('.content', this)` (`.content`, children of `this`)
- if we did not used an additional function callback for the slide, you might get the issue of the need to double-click some `DIV` elements, cause the `io` value of that particular element was not up to date for it's state, so to change that we just need to set for every slided element the same `io` state to the `.name` (the toggler) (`.closest()`) parent.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! May I ask you another question? I've renamed the .name divs to .newLevel and put the name of the div to a .name div. I'd like that if I click on the name of the div that's slides up all child .content div and all child .newLevel div, but on the next click it should only slides down .content and .newLevel divs on it's first level. So the children .content divs on further levels should be hidden until I clicks on it's immediate parent div's name. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Yes, but when I close a level it should also close it's sub levels.

Comment: @Crabman I'm a bit lost in what you explained. Please create a jsBin :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but the click is propagation. A click inside an inner `name` is also a click inside the outer `name`. Add this :

```
$('.name').click(function(e)//pass the event
{
   e.stopPropagation(); // prevent the event from bubbling.
   $(this).children('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

Also, you are using `.children`, which targets direct children only. If you want **all** childrens (*descendants*), use `.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop propagating the event so that it doesn't bubble up the tree -

```
$('.name').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/sSRJ4/